# append to file using only 'r' and 'w'

Tags: c, file-io

I have this problem where I have to append data to the end of file. But I should use only `'r'` and `'w'` modes. I am not allowed to use either `'a'` or `'a+'` or `'w+'` or `'r+'` modes.

So what I did is, putting the content of the file in a buffer, opening the file in `'w'` mode, then performing write operation. After that write the buffer's content to the file. It worked, but when I opened the file using `cat`, the output was not as expected. I could see some junk in between.
The code is as follow, assuming that the file already contains some data

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{   
    char str[50];
    char abuf[500];
    int szf;
    FILE *fp;

    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
    printf("enter string \n");
    gets(str);
    printf("string entered is: %s \n", str);
    memset(abuf, 0, sizeof(abuf));
    printf("done memset \n");
    fp=fopen("smple.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL) {  fopen("smple.txt","w");  }
    else{
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        printf("done fseek \n");
        szf=ftell(fp);
        printf("done ftell \n");
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("done fseek set \n");
        fread(abuf, sizeof(char), szf+1, fp);
        printf("abuf is: %s \n", abuf);
        fclose(fp);
        fp=fopen("smple.txt", "w"); 
        fwrite(str, sizeof(str), strlen(str), fp);}
        fwrite(abuf, sizeof(str), strlen(abuf), fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: `fwrite(str, sizeof(str), strlen(str), fp);` doesn't do what you think it does.  You should take a look at the documentation for `fwrite`.

Comment: oh ya right.. it should be fwrite(str, 1, strlen(str), fp); It worked..thank u :)

Comment: you lack a closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comment made by RetiredNinja, I'd also add that you've actually tried to prepend the data - adding the datato the start of the file, rather than the end. (abuf should be written to file before str)

You've also got a limit of just 500 bytes for the file, since you've not dynamically allocated the memory for abuf.

I propose the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char fileExists = 0;
    long existingLength;
    char *existingData;

    char inputBuffer[1024];
    printf("Enter text: ");
    gets(inputBuffer);

    FILE *output;
    output = fopen("smpl.txt", "r");
    if (output != NULL)
    {
        fseek(output, 0, SEEK_END);
        existingLength = ftell(output);
        existingData = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * existingLength);
        fseek(output, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(existingData, 1, existingLength, output);
        fclose(output);
        fileExists = 1;
    }

    output = fopen("smpl.txt", "w");

    if (fileExists)
        fwrite(existingData, sizeof(char), existingLength, output);

    fwrite(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer[0]), strlen(inputBuffer), output);

    fclose(output);
}
```